# how can I http POST to libraries with SP 2010's REST API?

Tags: 2010, javascript, library, rest

SP 2010's [REST api documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798339.aspx) cites an example that uses a list, whereas I wish to rely on a library (for example, "SharedDocuments"), because a standard named library already exists in every employee's personal SP site at my company.

I've managed to http GET read document resources stored in this standard employee personal site library; now I'd like to http POST resources there.

How can I http POST documents to a given library? (May I add that I am evaluating the 2010 SP REST API using Javascript.) As a related matter, how can I create directories in a library with the 2010 SP REST API (using Javascript)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have code I use to upload files using the filereader object.  The uploadFile function is called on the event change of a file input and passes the event.target.files to the function.  If you are using IE you will need to use a polyfill to provide the same functionality.  I have used https://github.com/Jahdrien/FileReader.

**Event Object:**

```
jQuery('#'  +  element.id).fileReader({
            id: 'fileReaderSWFObject',
            filereader: '/Site/SiteAssets/JS/lib/filereader.swf',
            expressInstall: '/Site/SiteAssets/JS/lib/expressInstall.swf',
            debugMode: true
 });    

jQuery('#' +  element.id).on('change', function (event) {
    console.log('fileChange');
    valueAccessor().uploadFile(event.target.files);
});
```

**File Upload Function**

```
self.uploadFile = function (files) {
            filereader = {},
            file = {},
            file = files[0];
            filereader = new FileReader();
            filereader.fi

lename = file.name;
                self.uploadFileName(file.name);
                self.uploadStatus('Reading File');

                filereader.onload = function () {
                    console.log('onload');

                    var data = filereader.result,
                    n = data.indexOf(";base64,") + 8;
                    //removing the first part of the dataurl give us the base64 bytes we need to feed to sharepoint
                    data = data.substring(n);
                    self.uploadStatus('Uploading File');
                    jQuery.when(uploadFile(filereader.filename, data)).done(function(results)
                    {
                        self.uploadStatus('Upload Complete');
                    });
                }


                filereader.onabort = function () {
                    alert("The upload was aborted.");
                };

                filereader.onerror = function () {
                    alert("An error occured while reading the file.");
                };
                //fire the onload function giving it the dataurl

                filereader.readAsDataURL(file);
        }
```

**Web Service Call**

```
 function uploadFile(FileName,FileData) {
         //FileData is a byte array   
console.log("uploading file");
            var url= "https://"+location.hostname+"/SiteName/FolderName/"+FileName;

             var soapEnv =
        "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' xmlns:soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'> \
            <soap:Body>\
                <CopyIntoItems xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/'>\
                    <SourceUrl>https://"+location.hostname+"/SiteName/FolerName/    </SourceUrl>\
                        <DestinationUrls>\
                            <string> "+ url + "</string>\
                        </DestinationUrls>\
                        <Fields>\
                            <FieldInformation Type='Text' DisplayName='Title' InternalName='Title' Value='Test' />\
                        </Fields>\
                    <Stream>"+ FileData +"</Stream>\
                </CopyIntoItems>\
            </soap:Body>\
        </soap:Envelope>";
          return  jQuery.ajax({
                url: "https://"+location.hostname+"/SiteName/_vti_bin/copy.asmx",
                beforeSend: function (xhr) { xhr.setRequestHeader("SOAPAction", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/CopyIntoItems"); },
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "xml",
                data: soapEnv,
                complete: processResult,
                contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\""
            }).promise();
        }
```